# Should Northern Cyprus be tagged separately from the Republic of Cyprus?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Our (few) existing questions about Northern Cyprus, like [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42046/staying-a-night-at-ercan-international-airport), are currently tagged `cyprus`.  The tag's description is:

> Cyprus, officially the Republic of Cyprus, is an island country in the
>   eastern Mediterranean Sea and is a member state of the European Union.

Which is fair enough in legal theory, but in practice places like Ercan are not controlled by the Republic of Cyprus, and entirely different procedures for visas etc apply.

Should we add a new `northern-cyprus` tag and retag where appropriate?

Comment: Need we make this political? Couldn't we just say it is a distinctive region of Cyprus that merits its own tag the same as [tag:hawaii] or [tag:quebec]?

Comment: It's not about politics, it's about the reality of travel in the area.

Comment: But then why do we need to have a thread about it?

Comment: Because this is a travel site, and we were possibly tagging it incorrectly in terms of travel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that we should add a new [northern-cyprus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/northern-cyprus) tag. Even it's only recognized by Turkey, different rules could apply for travellers there.

Comment: Agree. I had no idea they were separated, and if it's different visa requirements, then yes, we really, really should separate the tags.

Comment: I've gone ahead and created this.

Comment: How do people of northern Cyprus travel if their passports are only recognized by one country? sounds like a good question to me.

Comment: @MeNoTalk I think that they need to apply for Passports from the Republic of Cyprus first.

Comment: @Dirty-flow yup, I read that in the Wikipedia article after my comment...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see how it could *not* be about politics. To be sure, there are many travel-related issues created by the division but with a grand total of 12 questions, we could also keep one tag, possibly adjusting the description to acknowledge the problem.

Personally, I don't feel very strongly about this one way or the other but I think this possibility ought to be considered.

Incidentally, among the three questions about Northern Cyprus, one is closed and another one is really about the island as a whole and the relationship between both sides. So we have a tag for a single question about Ercan airport, another reason to get rid of it.

Comment: @Relaxed My answer is that we don't need two tags. But like I said, I don't feel very strongly about this, which I why I merely wrote that “we could also keep one tag”.

Comment: @pnuts I edited the question slightly after your comment. I don't think the situation in Greece would generate many questions about Northern Cyprus.